# Sequalize - highest PostgreSQL version supported

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm looking to use Sequalize library in a new Node.js project. However, I noticed it only supports version 6 of `pg` driver library. I'm not sure what is the highest version of PostgreSQL database that I can use it considering I want to use full-fledged JSON support?

I tried looking in https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres and https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize for any documentation or hint but couldn't find any.

Comment: JSON support has been in for a long time and PostgreSQL is good about backwards-compatibility. You should be fine using version 10.

Comment: @Ryan sorry if this is off-topic, but I'm new to NodeJS ecosystem. Is using Sequelize still a valid option considering it uses pg version 6 and not 7?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found on their support page.

node-postgres conforms to v3 of the PostgreSQL wire protocol. This means node-postgres supports PostgreSQL server 8.x - current

https://node-postgres.com/support

Answer (score 0):

Here is the supported PostgreSQL and `pg` based for the sequelize version you want to use.
https://sequelize.org/releases/#postgresql-support-table